# Pages and book problem - Tearing of a page from book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

There are a certain number of pages in a book. Bob tore a certain page out of the book and later found that the average of the remaining page numbers is $46 \frac{10}{13}$. What were the page numbers that Bob had torn ?

---

**Please let me know where am I going wrong with my approach :-**

Since the average of the remaining "page numbers" has 13 in the denominator , I can say that the remaining number of "page numbers" have to be a multiple of 13

So the remaining number of "page numbers" can be 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104.....

Accordingly the original number of "page numbers" in the book could be 15, 28, 41, 54, 67, 80, 93, 106...

Now, Sum of remaining "page numbers" + sum of the torn "page numbers" = sum of total "page numbers" initially

I started making cases now,

---

Case 1:- When original number of "page numbers" were 15

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 15, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (15*16)/2 = 120

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 13

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 13) = 120

which gives x to be a negative number

---

Case 2:- When original number of "page numbers" were 28

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 28, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (28*29)/2 = 406

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 26

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 26) = 406

x is still negative

---

Case 3:- When original number of "page numbers" were 41

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 28, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (41*42)/2 = 861

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 39

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 39) = 861

x is still negative :(

---

Case 4:- When original number of "page numbers" were 54

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 54, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (54*55)/2 = 1485

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 52

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 52) = 1485

x<0

---

Case 5:- When original number of "page numbers" were 67

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 67, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (67*68)/2 = 2278

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 65

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 65) = 2278

x<0

---

Case 6:- When original number of "page numbers" were 80

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 54, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (80*81)/2 = 3240

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 78

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 78) = 3240

x<0

---

Case 7:- When original number of "page numbers" were 93

So it would have "page numbers" from 1 till 93, therefore total of all "page numbers" would be (93*94)/2 = 4371

Sum of remaining "page numbers" =  $46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 91

Let sum of torn pages = x

x + ($46 \frac{10}{13}$ * 91) = 4371

x=115   (:O)

now is it that 2 consecutive page numbers m+m+1=115

one page number will be 57 and other 58 and both of them even lie in the range of 93 "page numbers" as well

---

Comment: Page numbers are usually printed on both sides of a page in a book.

Comment: Yes I did consider that, could you please point at which step specifically have I mistaken ?

Comment: I feel really bad, because you did a lot of casework...but if the number of page numbers is reduced by two, why is your denominator $n-1$? There are simpler ways to solve this, too - I'm just writing one up as an answer.

Comment: 2 Page numbers would be removed ; but the number of pages would still be (n-1) right ? and for calculating the sum of remaining page numbers we would multiply average of remaining page numbers * number of pages remaining ? so initially if we had n pages, we would have n-1 pages left right ?

Comment: The page numbers go from $1$ to $n$ (there are $n$ of them). When a page is torn out of the book, two page numbers are removed, leaving $n-2$. It is not a nicely worded problem (possibly a deliberate trick).

Comment: Shouldn't a book with n pages have page numbers from 1 to 2n ? how will there be 1 to n page numbers ? Each page will have 2 page numbers on opposite sides of that particular page

Comment: If the page numbers are from 1 to 28, what is their sum? How did you get $14 * 15 / 2$? $\quad$ You seem to be sometimes realizing that pages and page numbers are distinct, but sometimes thinking they are the same thing. EG Average of page numbers is 46 10/13, but you multiple by number of pages and not the number of page numbers.  $\quad$ To me, that is causing your confusion.

Comment: Thank you @CalvinLin for pointing out the calculation error, I have corrected it now.

I have considered them to be distinct only ; Number of pages will always be n-1 and that needs to be a multiple of 13, as per my understanding

Comment: I don't think you've thought through the full implications of this confusion. For example, If the page numbers are from 1 to 28, and 1 page is torn, then 1/ How many page numbers are left? 2/ What is the minimum of that sum? 3/ If their average is 46 10/13, what is the sum of the leftover page numbers?$\quad$ I'm glad to see that you fixed the initial error that I pointed out. However, you should still look through the rest of that case to ensure that you fixed your confusion in every instance.

Comment: 1) Page numbers left would be 26

2) Minimum sum of pages torn would be 1+2=3

Additionally,  number of pages now in the book would be 14-1=13

Comment: (See question 3 that I edited in, alongside the rest of the comment)

Comment: 3) Sum of left over page numbers = (Average of page numbers of the left over pages) * (Number of pages left in the book) = 46 10/13 * 14  ?  This is as per my understanding

Comment: No, I didn't ask for the sum of leftover pages. I asked for the sum of leftover page NUMBERS. $\quad$ Like I mentioned, you need to be very aware that these are 2 distinct concepts, even though the terminlogy is very similar (which lends to the confusion). $\quad$ The average of the page NUMBERS is 46 10/13. The average of the pages? Not given.

Comment: I have edited that

Comment: " Sum of left over $\color{blue}{PAGE NUMBERS }$= (Average of $\color{blue}{PAGE NUMBERS}$ of the left over pages) * (Number of $\color{red}{PAGES}$ left in the book)"  is wrong. Like I mentioned, you need to be very aware that these are 2 distinct concepts, even though the terminlogy is very similar

Comment: (Sorry if it seems like I'm just clubbing you over the head on this.)

Comment: how is this wrong ? I am struggling to understand  ; I do get your point that "number of pages" and "page numbers are different" ;  Number of pages will always be n-1 as per my understanding

Comment: The correct version should be  Sum of left over $\color{blue}{PAGE \, NUMBERS}$ = (Average of $\color{blue}{PAGE \, NUMBERS}$ of the left over pages) * (Number of $\color{blue}{PAGE \, NUMBERS}$ left in the book) = 46 10/13 * $\color{blue}{26}$.

Comment: This may or may not help, but perhaps try thinking of the "number of page numbers" as book has versus the "number of pages" it has. Or, maybe rewrite everything and say the book had a leaf torn out!

Comment: @CalvinLin omg, I believe I understood your point.  There was some serious play of words.  Let me try to incorporate this new learning into my solution and try again.... Could you review it once I edit it the original post ... thank you so much for sticking around and helping me get the correct understanding of it

Comment: thanks @ChrisLewis yeah that helped !

Comment: Yup, ping me when you've made the corresponding edits to your solution. $\quad$ FWIW You still have another misconception (so you won't be able to cleanly get to the answer). See if you can spot it as you clean up your solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin I have edited the solution as per my current understanding, now the issue is that x is coming out to be negative only in every case ? is it due to the other misconception which you were referring to ?

Comment: Humor me, run through 4 more cases.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think I got it on 7th case itself :O

Comment: Thank you so much @CalvinLin for the clarification of doubts :D ; I have a question , was there any way in which I could have directly come to this case , instead of doing the same thing so many times ?

Comment: See Chris solution, which explains why the answer should be around $ 2 \times 46 \frac{10}{13}$, so your guess of $93$ is the first case we should try.  $\quad$ What "x is negative" really meant was that you weren't using enough pages, which is why you had to go up higher further. If you solved for the specific values, you'd have noticed that they were getting less negative, thereby motivating trying a few more. Conversely, after going past $ n > 100$, you'd realize that $x > n$ meaning we used too many pages.

Comment: Congrats on successfully struggling through this and pushing through! Give yourself a pat on the back! I'm honestly impressed that you kept at it.

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments on the original question, the issue with the logic appears to be some confusion about pages vs page numbers.

I think there's a secondary issue of going for cases a bit too early - it's worth thinking heuristically about the problem first to get a feel for what sensible answers might look like.

Before going into cases, it's worth trying to get a feel for the problem. Ripping out a single page won't change the average by much. What's the total of all page numbers in a book with page numbers up to $n$? It's the $n^{\text{th}}$ triangular number, ie $\frac12 n(n+1)$, so the average is $\frac12 (n+1)$. In other words, without really doing any work, we know the page numbers should go up to around $100$.

You can just do cases here and find the solution, but in case it's of interest I've put the rest of a solution below (spoiler alert!).

---

Say the torn out page has numbers $k$ and $k+1$ on it. This, with the given information, gives us
$$\frac{\frac12 n(n+1)-2k-1}{n-2} = 46\frac{10}{13}=\frac{608}{13}$$

As you noticed, this means $n-2$ is a multiple of $13$; let's say $n=13m+2$. Now, substituting and tidying up a bit, the above expression becomes
$$ 169 m^2 - 1151 m + 4 = 4k$$

We need $0 < k < n = 13m+2$, so that
$$ 0 < 169 m^2 - 1151 m + 4 < 52m+8$$

Solving this, we find that $6.8 < m < 7.1$, so the only possibility is $m=7$; and this does indeed work. We find the original book's page numbers went up to $93$, and the page with numbers $57$ and $58$ was removed.

---

If the denominator in the problem had been something less convenient, this approach would still work on the equation for $k$ in terms of $n$, but there may have been a larger range of cases to check.

Comment: Your solution is fine, but FWIW OP is asking for where they went wrong in their logic, and not for a solution.

Comment: That's fair. I got a bit carried away with how to solve it nicely! I've reformatted my post to try to address the question more directly.

Comment: Sorry for piling on, but the secondary issue is that OP has another misconception of "every page has 2 page numbers". That is true of most pages, but not necessarily the first and last page. EG That's how you got to 93 page numbers, whereas OP could only have $2n$ page numbers.

Comment: That's sort of the same issue though, isn't it? In any case, it looks as though OP is going to reword a bit so I might just see where that lands. Quite interesting meanwhile to think to what extent it's possible (with sensible numbers) to get ambiguity in this type of problem.

Comment: Yea, might be nitpicking. $\quad$ This problem skin was one of the first that I came across where there could be so many ambiguities esp  with the first and last page, that could make it very hard to solve. However, it might become even more confusing as people get used to swiping on digital books and don't quite understand why "a page has 2 sides".

Comment: Please don't tear a page out of your e-reader.

Comment: +1 With OP's edit, now the "Let's get a feel for what a sensible answer looks like" is very relevant.